does monkey patching still works in android gradle
So I read this post on the monkey patching in Android, and seems quite an interesting approach to fix AGP bugs before they get fixed, but when I try to use the approach by creating a class in the buildSrc with the same name and package of the targetClass nothing will happen and the original class is getting loaded.
this doesn't work anymore or I'm missing something.
